# searching for a match then replacing a value after this match with a value from the previous line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have multiple files that contain thousands of lines of the following pattern:

```
O   HOH     1      11.700 -11.906   1.533
H   HOH     0      12.561 -12.318   1.596
H   HOH     0      11.445 -12.031   0.627
O   HOH     2      17.897   8.999  -0.104
H   HOH     0      18.444   8.521   0.516
H   HOH     0      17.127   8.457  -0.223
O   HOH     3      -0.688  10.310 -15.189
H   HOH     0      -0.760   9.366 -15.055
H   HOH     0      -0.494  10.665 -14.324
O   HOH     4     -10.418   3.733   4.069
H   HOH     0      -9.928   3.726   4.897
H   HOH     0     -11.222   4.218   4.268
O   HOH     5       2.655  -8.910  13.338
H   HOH     0       2.377  -9.739  13.737
H   HOH     0       1.847  -8.531  12.992
O   HOH     6      -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H   HOH     0       0.455  -1.460 -18.924
H   HOH     0      -0.571  -0.343 -18.895
O   HOH     7      14.338 -15.985  -1.467
H   HOH     0      15.129 -15.647  -1.886
H   HOH     0      13.854 -16.408  -2.175
O   HOH     8     -15.510  -7.073   1.857
H   HOH     0     -15.526  -6.116   1.874
H   HOH     0     -16.341  -7.321   1.464
O   HOH     9       9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH     0       9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH     0       9.943   6.018  -7.768
.
.
.
.
O   HOH  999999     9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH     0       9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH     0       9.943   6.018  -7.768
```

what I need is to replace each 2 sequential instants of `'H   HOH     0'` with `'H   HOH     xxx'` where `xxx` is the value right above the 0s

what I have tried was that, I split the big file into 3-line files using

```
split -l 3 foo
```

then using awk I copied the needed value to another file

```
awk 'NR==1 print $3' > foo--
```

then tried to use sed to replace the pattern by reading the file foo-- and replacing the ' 0 ' in foo

```
sed -e '/  0  /{r foo--' -e 'd}' foo
```

but that didn't work

pretty sure there is a better way to do this

The end result should look like this:

```
O   HOH     1      11.700 -11.906   1.533
H   HOH     1      12.561 -12.318   1.596
H   HOH     1      11.445 -12.031   0.627
O   HOH     2      17.897   8.999  -0.104
H   HOH     2      18.444   8.521   0.516
H   HOH     2      17.127   8.457  -0.223
O   HOH     3      -0.688  10.310 -15.189
H   HOH     3      -0.760   9.366 -15.055
H   HOH     3      -0.494  10.665 -14.324
O   HOH     4     -10.418   3.733   4.069
H   HOH     4      -9.928   3.726   4.897
H   HOH     4     -11.222   4.218   4.268
O   HOH     5       2.655  -8.910  13.338
H   HOH     5       2.377  -9.739  13.737
H   HOH     5       1.847  -8.531  12.992
O   HOH     6      -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H   HOH     6       0.455  -1.460 -18.924
H   HOH     6      -0.571  -0.343 -18.895
.
.
.
O   HOH     99999      -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H   HOH     99999       0.455  -1.460 -18.924
H   HOH     99999      -0.571  -0.343 -18.895
```

Comment: Does `H   HOH     0` always occur in two consecutive lines?

Comment: @Cyrus.. yes it does

Comment: What happens if it occurs 4 times in a row?

Comment: @Graeme. These are actually Cartesian coordinates of water molecules. A water molecule has the formula H2O. So in this case there is always one O and 2 consecutive H atoms. There won't be 4 instances of  ' H  HOH  0 '   in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the values you want if you don't care about spacing between fields:

```
$ awk '$1=="H"{$3=p} {p=$3} 1' file
O   HOH     1      11.700 -11.906   1.533
H HOH 1 12.561 -12.318 1.596
H HOH 1 11.445 -12.031 0.627
O   HOH     2      17.897   8.999  -0.104
H HOH 2 18.444 8.521 0.516
H HOH 2 17.127 8.457 -0.223
O   HOH     3      -0.688  10.310 -15.189
H HOH 3 -0.760 9.366 -15.055
H HOH 3 -0.494 10.665 -14.324
O   HOH     4     -10.418   3.733   4.069
H HOH 4 -9.928 3.726 4.897
H HOH 4 -11.222 4.218 4.268
O   HOH     5       2.655  -8.910  13.338
H HOH 5 2.377 -9.739 13.737
H HOH 5 1.847 -8.531 12.992
O   HOH     6      -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H HOH 6 0.455 -1.460 -18.924
H HOH 6 -0.571 -0.343 -18.895
O   HOH     7      14.338 -15.985  -1.467
H HOH 7 15.129 -15.647 -1.886
H HOH 7 13.854 -16.408 -2.175
O   HOH     8     -15.510  -7.073   1.857
H HOH 8 -15.526 -6.116 1.874
H HOH 8 -16.341 -7.321 1.464
O   HOH     9       9.155   6.561  -7.729
H HOH 9 9.419 7.335 -7.245
H HOH 9 9.943 6.018 -7.768
O   HOH  999999     9.155   6.561  -7.729
H HOH 999999 9.419 7.335 -7.245
H HOH 999999 9.943 6.018 -7.768
```

or space-separated with the last 4 fields right-aligned:

```
$ awk '$1=="H"{$3=p} {p=$3} 1' file | column -t -R3,4,5,6
O  HOH       1   11.700  -11.906    1.533
H  HOH       1   12.561  -12.318    1.596
H  HOH       1   11.445  -12.031    0.627
O  HOH       2   17.897    8.999   -0.104
H  HOH       2   18.444    8.521    0.516
H  HOH       2   17.127    8.457   -0.223
O  HOH       3   -0.688   10.310  -15.189
H  HOH       3   -0.760    9.366  -15.055
H  HOH       3   -0.494   10.665  -14.324
O  HOH       4  -10.418    3.733    4.069
H  HOH       4   -9.928    3.726    4.897
H  HOH       4  -11.222    4.218    4.268
O  HOH       5    2.655   -8.910   13.338
H  HOH       5    2.377   -9.739   13.737
H  HOH       5    1.847   -8.531   12.992
O  HOH       6   -0.191   -1.010  -19.469
H  HOH       6    0.455   -1.460  -18.924
H  HOH       6   -0.571   -0.343  -18.895
O  HOH       7   14.338  -15.985   -1.467
H  HOH       7   15.129  -15.647   -1.886
H  HOH       7   13.854  -16.408   -2.175
O  HOH       8  -15.510   -7.073    1.857
H  HOH       8  -15.526   -6.116    1.874
H  HOH       8  -16.341   -7.321    1.464
O  HOH       9    9.155    6.561   -7.729
H  HOH       9    9.419    7.335   -7.245
H  HOH       9    9.943    6.018   -7.768
O  HOH  999999    9.155    6.561   -7.729
H  HOH  999999    9.419    7.335   -7.245
H  HOH  999999    9.943    6.018   -7.768
```

or in TSV format:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{$3=($1=="H" ? p : $3); p=$3} 1' file
O       HOH     1       11.700  -11.906 1.533
H       HOH     1       12.561  -12.318 1.596
H       HOH     1       11.445  -12.031 0.627
O       HOH     2       17.897  8.999   -0.104
H       HOH     2       18.444  8.521   0.516
H       HOH     2       17.127  8.457   -0.223
O       HOH     3       -0.688  10.310  -15.189
H       HOH     3       -0.760  9.366   -15.055
H       HOH     3       -0.494  10.665  -14.324
O       HOH     4       -10.418 3.733   4.069
H       HOH     4       -9.928  3.726   4.897
H       HOH     4       -11.222 4.218   4.268
O       HOH     5       2.655   -8.910  13.338
H       HOH     5       2.377   -9.739  13.737
H       HOH     5       1.847   -8.531  12.992
O       HOH     6       -0.191  -1.010  -19.469
H       HOH     6       0.455   -1.460  -18.924
H       HOH     6       -0.571  -0.343  -18.895
O       HOH     7       14.338  -15.985 -1.467
H       HOH     7       15.129  -15.647 -1.886
H       HOH     7       13.854  -16.408 -2.175
O       HOH     8       -15.510 -7.073  1.857
H       HOH     8       -15.526 -6.116  1.874
H       HOH     8       -16.341 -7.321  1.464
O       HOH     9       9.155   6.561   -7.729
H       HOH     9       9.419   7.335   -7.245
H       HOH     9       9.943   6.018   -7.768
O       HOH     999999  9.155   6.561   -7.729
H       HOH     999999  9.419   7.335   -7.245
H       HOH     999999  9.943   6.018   -7.768
```

If you need to retain the original spacing, though, then with GNU awk for the 4th arg to split() this will retain whatever spacing you started with:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    if ($1 == "H") {
        split(prev,pflds,FS,pseps)
        n = split($0,flds,FS,seps)
        seps[2] = pseps[2]
        flds[3] = pflds[3]
        seps[3] = sprintf("%*s",length(pseps[3]) + length(pflds[4]) - length(flds[4]),"")
        $0 = ""
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            $0 = $0 flds[i] seps[i]
        }
    }
    print
    prev = $0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
O   HOH     1      11.700 -11.906   1.533
H   HOH     1      12.561 -12.318   1.596
H   HOH     1      11.445 -12.031   0.627
O   HOH     2      17.897   8.999  -0.104
H   HOH     2      18.444   8.521   0.516
H   HOH     2      17.127   8.457  -0.223
O   HOH     3      -0.688  10.310 -15.189
H   HOH     3      -0.760   9.366 -15.055
H   HOH     3      -0.494  10.665 -14.324
O   HOH     4     -10.418   3.733   4.069
H   HOH     4      -9.928   3.726   4.897
H   HOH     4     -11.222   4.218   4.268
O   HOH     5       2.655  -8.910  13.338
H   HOH     5       2.377  -9.739  13.737
H   HOH     5       1.847  -8.531  12.992
O   HOH     6      -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H   HOH     6       0.455  -1.460 -18.924
H   HOH     6      -0.571  -0.343 -18.895
O   HOH     7      14.338 -15.985  -1.467
H   HOH     7      15.129 -15.647  -1.886
H   HOH     7      13.854 -16.408  -2.175
O   HOH     8     -15.510  -7.073   1.857
H   HOH     8     -15.526  -6.116   1.874
H   HOH     8     -16.341  -7.321   1.464
O   HOH     9       9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH     9       9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH     9       9.943   6.018  -7.768
O   HOH  999999     9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH  999999     9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH  999999     9.943   6.018  -7.768
```

Comment: for the one involving `column`, I am getting `column: invalid option -- 'R' `

Comment: OK, guess it needs GNU column for right-alignment then and you must not have it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you need in `awk`, but keeping to format nice and tidy will require using `FIELDWIDTHS` and `fprinf`. The problem is due to `awk` stripping leading and trailing *whitespace* when it must recompute the record, such as when the record is changed. Unchanged records are not modified in this way. This creates a challenge when providing tabular output.

To use the `FIELDWIDTHS` of each field, provide a list of the widths in the `BEGIN` rule. Example:

```
awk '
    BEGIN  { FIELDWIDTHS = "1 6 8 10 8 8" }
    $1 == "O" {n = $3}
    $1 == "H" {$3 = n}
    {printf "%s%6s%8s%10s%8s%8s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
' file
```

(**note:** `FIELDWIDTHS` is a GNU `awk` feature)

With your data, removing the `...`, you can just copy/middle-mouse-paste at the command line to test, e.g.

```
$ awk '
>     BEGIN  { FIELDWIDTHS = "1 6 8 10 8 8" }
>     $1 == "O" {n = $3}
>     $1 == "H" {$3 = n}
>     {printf "%s%6s%8s%10s%8s%8s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}
> ' file
O   HOH     1      11.700 -11.906   1.533
H   HOH     1      12.561 -12.318   1.596
H   HOH     1      11.445 -12.031   0.627
O   HOH     2      17.897   8.999  -0.104
H   HOH     2      18.444   8.521   0.516
H   HOH     2      17.127   8.457  -0.223
O   HOH     3      -0.688  10.310 -15.189
H   HOH     3      -0.760   9.366 -15.055
H   HOH     3      -0.494  10.665 -14.324
O   HOH     4     -10.418   3.733   4.069
H   HOH     4      -9.928   3.726   4.897
H   HOH     4     -11.222   4.218   4.268
O   HOH     5       2.655  -8.910  13.338
H   HOH     5       2.377  -9.739  13.737
H   HOH     5       1.847  -8.531  12.992
O   HOH     6      -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H   HOH     6       0.455  -1.460 -18.924
H   HOH     6      -0.571  -0.343 -18.895
O   HOH     7      14.338 -15.985  -1.467
H   HOH     7      15.129 -15.647  -1.886
H   HOH     7      13.854 -16.408  -2.175
O   HOH     8     -15.510  -7.073   1.857
H   HOH     8     -15.526  -6.116   1.874
H   HOH     8     -16.341  -7.321   1.464
O   HOH     9       9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH     9       9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH     9       9.943   6.018  -7.768
O   HOH  999999     9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH  999999     9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH  999999     9.943   6.018  -7.768
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '$1=="O"{p=$3}; $1=="H" {$3=p} {printf("%s %5s      %s %10.3f %7.3f %7.3f\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6)} ' file
```

Output:

```
O   HOH      1     11.700 -11.906   1.533
H   HOH      1     12.561 -12.318   1.596
H   HOH      1     11.445 -12.031   0.627
O   HOH      2     17.897   8.999  -0.104
H   HOH      2     18.444   8.521   0.516
H   HOH      2     17.127   8.457  -0.223
O   HOH      3     -0.688  10.310 -15.189
H   HOH      3     -0.760   9.366 -15.055
H   HOH      3     -0.494  10.665 -14.324
O   HOH      4    -10.418   3.733   4.069
H   HOH      4     -9.928   3.726   4.897
H   HOH      4    -11.222   4.218   4.268
O   HOH      5      2.655  -8.910  13.338
H   HOH      5      2.377  -9.739  13.737
H   HOH      5      1.847  -8.531  12.992
O   HOH      6     -0.191  -1.010 -19.469
H   HOH      6      0.455  -1.460 -18.924
H   HOH      6     -0.571  -0.343 -18.895
O   HOH      7     14.338 -15.985  -1.467
H   HOH      7     15.129 -15.647  -1.886
.
.
.
O   HOH      999999      9.155   6.561  -7.729
H   HOH      999999      9.419   7.335  -7.245
H   HOH      999999      9.943   6.018  -7.768
```

Comment: That would behave the same in any awk, there's nothing GNU-only in it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
awk '{ if($1=="H" && $2=="HOH" && $3=="0") $3=val; else val=$3 } 1'
```

Alternatively, to preserve field widths:

```
awk '{
    if($1=="H" && $2=="HOH" && $3=="0")
        sub(sprintf("0 {1,%d}", length(val)), val " ")
    else
        val=$3
} 1'
```

Comment: It does for the values, but the output format is scrambled. Second method is much better but `999999` records are offset. (due to inconsistent format in the input file) I like your idea of `sub`.

Comment: @David, yes! Preserving original field widths with `awk` is difficult.

Comment: Chuckling -- it took me almost an hour to stumble across the solution `:)`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^H\s+HOH\s+0\s/!{h;b};N;/\nH\s+HOH\s+0\s/{G;s/0(.*\n.[^0]*)0(.*)\n\S\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*/\3\1\3\2/};P;D' file
```

If a line does not begin `H   HOH     0`, print as normal and retain a copy  in the hold space. Otherwise, append the following line and if that too begins `H   HOH     0`, then append the copy from the hold space and using substitution rearrange the first two lines to the desired format. In all other cases, print the next line and repeat.

In more detail, as requested:

- `/^H\s+HOH\s+0\s/!{h;b}` If a line does not begin `H   HOH     0`, print as normal and retain a copy in the hold space (`h` copies to the hold space, `b` breaks out of the sed command cycle, prints the current line in the pattern space and if available, fetches the next line).
- `N` The current line begins `H   HOH     0` append the next line.
- `/\nH\s+HOH\s+0\s/` The appended line also begins `H   HOH     0` so:
- `G` Append the copy of the hold space i.e. the last line that did not begin `H   HOH     0`, and:
- `s/0(.*\n.[^0]*)0(.*)\n\S\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*/\3\1\3\2/` Substitute the 3rd fields in both the last two lines with the 3rd field from the copy of the hold space.
- `P` Print upto and including the first newline.
- `D` Delete upto and including the first newline.

The last two sed commands cater for the case where the line appended to the pattern space does not match the first three fields of the second. This allows the first of those lines to be printed as normal and the second to be treated as if that line had been presented afresh.

Comment: I really like the `sed` solution. can you please explain it in more details?

Comment: This worked out perfectly. The advantage of `sed` is that I didn't have to worry about the column spacings produced by `awk`. I am changing the accepted answer to this one.

Comment: `I didn't have to worry about the column spacings produced by awk` - did you look at the output spacings from the sed command for the `999999` lines and think about how it'd behave with other multi-digit 3rd column values? You don't have to worry about the column spacings produced by awk either if you don't line up all the output columns. Aren't you even slightly concerned that you MIGHT not be able to update this sed script if/when you want to do anything just slightly different in future?

Comment: @EdMorton. You are actually right, I had to perform at least 2 more `sed` commands to fix the spacing produced by the larger numbers. I guess `awk` is a better fit in this case.

Comment: yes it is and you can actually read it and trivially modify it if/when your requirements change and the awk scripts I posted at least will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.